# How to debug undefined method form_with error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the error:

`undefined form_with for #<#<Class:0x7ac62e0>:0x551e5a8>
in articles#new`

The error occurs in the following file: `new.html.erb`
Which has:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@article] , local: true) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><enter code here`br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
```

And the controller `articles_controller.rb` has:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

Comment: I get the same problem. Funny cos I'm following the RoR tutorial in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-articles !!
Rails version is 5.0.6, Ruby is 2.3.1

Comment: For anyone else who has followed that tutorial and had this problem - upgrade Rails to a version 5.1 or greater and it will solve the issue with form_with.  More info https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your controller just has new command see sample below for create instance variable @article

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController 
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with @article do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Enter title: " %> 
  <%= f.text_field :title %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error while working on nested routes. It occurred when the controller routes are defined as nested under another controller's route.

For example:

```
resources :authors do 
   resource :books, only: [index, :new]
end
```

it will create following routes:

```
/authors/author_id/books/:id
/authors/author_id/books/new
```

The method `form_with` try to execute the method `book_path`. But it  is defined as `author_books_path`.

I found the solution by adding extra `resources :books` outside of the `resources :books` block.

```
resources :books

resources :authors do 
   resource :books, only: [:index, :new]
end
```

**Edit:**
This solution will build the form without error but action URL won't be  be correct because it will use `books/..` instead of `author/:author_id/books`.  That's why it is better use `form_for` instead of `form_with` while working on nested routes by passing parent and child model in a array.

```
<% form_for [@author, @book] do |form| %>
```